# How I can use AutoLayout with these UIButtons?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, swift2

I want to add Custom UIButtons as shown below, with W = 100 and H = 100 , so when I tried to use Equal widths and Equal Height and Aspect ratio from the Constraints window it didn't work great :/

[image]

so what i have to do ?

Thanks.

Comment: From what I can see, you might want to take a look into UICollectionView - http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1

Comment: Please use UICollectionView, otherwise if you have to constraint the button, try to set up left and right, then bottom left and right, then work your way around it.

Comment: Thirding UICollectionView. Any time you want a grid layout, that should be your first thought. Only consider other options if you can find a really good reason why it won't work or can't be made to.

Comment: okay i'll take a look on UICollectionView